# why does toLowerCase() not work within a replace

Tags: javascript

This code, to my thinking, should return `aha aha aha`, but it returns `Aha Aha Aha`

```
"Aha Aha Aha".replace(/([A-Z])/g,"$1".toLowerCase());
```

Same with toUpperCase()...

```
"Aha Aha Aha".replace(/([a-z])/g,"$1".toUpperCase());
```

Any explanation why this is happening?

Comment: `"$1".toUpperCase() == "$1"`. That's what you're passing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are applying `.toUpperCase` to the string `"$1"`, which is of course left unchanged. The unchanged string is then passed to the `.replace` function, and the result is... well, nothing happens.

The correct way of doing this would be to use a callback:

```
str.replace(/[a-z]/g,function(m) {return m.toUpperCase();});
```

(I'm assuming of course that this is an exercise - in this particular case, `str.toUpperCase()` directly would be much better!)

Passing a callback to `.replace()` is a very powerful thing. The important thing to be aware of is that the arguments passed to it will be the whole match first, then the first subpattern and so on. That is why I have removed the `()` in your regex - they are unnecessary.

Comment: I was just reading thoroughly through this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142922/replace-a-regex-capture-group-with-uppercase-in-javascript which explains