# String in bracket all in caps

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, lodash

I have a use case where I want to control all the char in the bracket to uppercase.

For example, if there's a string `Laugh out Loud (lol)` I want to convert it to `Laugh Out Loud (LOL)`

something like this, Where applying in a string first letter to be cap and if bracket then it should all convert into all caps.

Few examples:
`Point of view (pov)` to `Point Of View (POV)`

`What the hell` to `What The Hell`

it should also work if only string without brackets.

how can I achieve this in JS?

I am able to achieve it to put all the letter caps
`_.startCase(_.toLower('Point of view (pov)'))`

The result is `Point Of View (pov)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this if you first [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) ths string with empty string and then if it starts with ('(') and ends with (')') then you uppercase whole string else upper case only first character

```js
const str = 'Laugh out Loud (lol)';
const result = str
    .split(' ')
    .map((s) =>
        s.startsWith('(') && s.endsWith(')')
            ? s.toUpperCase()
            : s.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1),
    )
    .join(' ');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48994019/1115360) to do something like:

```
_.startCase('Point of view (pov)').replace(/.*(\(.*\))/, function($0, $1) {return $0.replace($1, $1.toUpperCase());});
```

Or using an arrow function:

```
_.startCase('Point of view (pov)').replace(/.*(\(.*\))/, ($0, $1) => $0.replace($1, $1.toUpperCase()));
```

(I didn't see any need for the _.toLower().)